# Site URL has been been identified as malicious and/or abusive

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

This question has been around but my scenario is pretty tricky. I'm in the half-way of developing and launching a pretty large Facebook application (website) in Google App Engine and brought my own custom domain to point to the app id.

In the Facebook apps panel I registered :

- 1 application for the custom domain
- 1 application for the subdomain given by google app engine

Few days I've been testing the application through the custom domain. I forgot to change the redirect URL in my authentication URL, its value was still left as the subdomain URL given by app engine. So, the login process used to start from my custom domain and reach the subdomain in the address bar.

Facebook has been showing notifications that the custom domain is pretending to be a website that it is not and asked my testers to reset their Facebook password. I didn't promote that URL any longer. We continued testing OK with the subdomain URL.

Now in the Facebook apps dashboard. I can't make any configuration changes in my custom domain configurations. Its showing

```
Error
App Domains: li__ke__2__marry.c__om (without __) is not a valid domain.
Site URL has been been identified as malicious and/or abusive.
```

It's basically a misunderstanding, the Facebook algorithm must have assumed that my custom domain must be doing something malicious after tracking its activity. Actually, it is not, and I'm not blaming Facebook algorithm for this mishap.

**My question is :** How to apply to have this negative rating removed? Facebook is a very reputed product, and I hope they follow the most basic principle : every **in** should be made with an **out**. If they have a feature to blacklist I'm hoping to get a place where I can file a False Detection/Re-Classify Requests. It hasn't cheated anybody and all the few people that used it were my friends and to my laziness I was not testing it in sandbox mode nor did I register/configure any of them as application testers! But that doesn't mean my URL is malicious.

A [similar request](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/505594746176481) in the bug report feature of Facebook was rejected marking that it should be put in the Stack Overflow community and even in the Stack Overflow community, I found someone authoritative closing a similar question asking them to post it in the bugs section of Facebook. [This link](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=407303956050174) from the community for the exact problem forwards the user to Stack Overflow itself.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/244560538958131) is a form for appealing blocked content (in your case URL). However there are very few chances of getting unblocked your URL but still you may try this form and hoping to get reply from Facebook. In any case if your URL is unblocked there is a high probability that your future users will see a captcha when visiting your app from mobile devices. So I can recommend to change the URL and continue developing with other URL.

Comment: Link in answer is dead - *"Page not found | This page isn't available"*.